# What's the best way to debug ionic/angularjs event handler bugs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, ionic-framework

I have a bug in an ionic app where (using breakpoints) I can see a controller register an event listener using `$on` and the corresponding event being `$broadcast` on `$rootScope` but the listener doesn't process the event.  I suspect that this is a scoping issue but beyond setting breakpoints in Chrome, I don't know the best way to debug this.  For example, is it possible to list all registered listeners and their scope?

**Update**
I actually resolved my issue by reading http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/ but I'm still interested in this type of debugging tool.

Comment: Check it out [ng-inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj).

Comment: ng-inspector seems to be "document-centric".  I didn't see it reporting any event listeners.  If it does, then they're buried somewhere within the output.  I hoping for something that lists _only_ event-related output.